# Inline reordering of substrings via bash

Tags: bash, awk, inline

Assume a text file that contains specific lines whose word order should be altered. The words (substrings) are delimited by single whitespaces. The lines to be altered can be identified by their first character (e.g., ">").

```
# cat test.txt
>3 test This is
foo bar baz
foo bar qux
>2 test This is
foo bar baz
>1 test This is
foo bar qux
```

What command (probably in `awk`) would you use to apply the same ordering process across all lines starting with the key character?

```
# cat test.txt | sought_command
>This is test 3
foo bar baz
foo bar qux
>This is test 2
foo bar baz
>This is test 1
foo bar qux
```

Comment: don't understand the sorting rule....

Comment: What have you tried? And is there a more abstract definition of the input and output which can make the reordering rules more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it using awk:

```
awk 'sub(/^>/, "") { print ">"$3, $4, $2, $1; next } 1' file
```

`sub` returns *true* (1) when it makes a substitution. The `1` at the end is the shortest *true* condition, to trigger the default action `{ print }`.

Comment: Wow!. The same script as mine but optimized!

Answer (score 1):

According to your example, like this:

```
awk '$1~"^>" {sub(">","",$1);print ">"$3,$4,$2,$1;next} {print}' test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. Plain and simple!

Comment: The `~` operator is for regexp comparisons so the thing on the right side of the expression is a regexp, not a string, and so should be enclosed in regexp delimiters, `/.../`, not string delimiters, `"..."`. When you use string delimiters in a regexp context awk has to parse the string twice, first to turn it into a regexp and then again to use it as a regexp and that has consequences, including requiring you to double up on any escape characters, e.g. `/foo\.bar/` vs `$0~"foo\\.bar"`. So you should use `$1~/^>/`, not `$1~"^>"`.

Comment: Thanks for the information @EdMorton!. Thanks to you know I understand why I had problems with the scape characters. I'll use `/../` from now on with the `~` operator.

Comment: You're welcome but this doesn't just apply when using the `~` operator, it's in every regexp context, e.g. the 2nd arg to match(), the 1st arg to sub()/gsub()/gensub(), and the 3rd arg to split().

Answer (score 0):

The tool best suited for simple substitutions on individual lines is sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/>([^ ]+)( [^ ]+ )(.*)/>\3\2\1/' file
>This is test 3
foo bar baz
foo bar qux
>This is test 2
foo bar baz
>This is test 1
foo bar qux
```

Awk is the right tool for anything more complicated/interesting. Note that unlike the awk solutions you've received so far the above will continue to work if/when you have more than 4 "words" on a line, e.g.:

```
$ cat file
>3 test Now is the Winter of our discontent
foo bar baz
foo bar qux
>2 test This is
foo bar baz
>1 test This is
foo bar qux

$ sed -E 's/>([^ ]+)( [^ ]+ )(.*)/>\3\2\1/' file
>Now is the Winter of our discontent test 3
foo bar baz
foo bar qux
>This is test 2
foo bar baz
>This is test 1
foo bar qux

$ awk 'sub(/^>/, "") { print ">"$3, $4, $2, $1; next } 1' file
>Now is test 3
foo bar baz
foo bar qux
>This is test 2
foo bar baz
>This is test 1
foo bar qux
```